# Entity Not Mapped - Entity Model Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having a lot of difficulty with the Entity Model Framework.

I'm just learning how to use this, so please bear with me.

This is the exception, along with the line of code that it gets thrown on:

[image]

This is what the model looks like, along with the model that it inherits from

[image]

This is what the mapping details looks like: (Top of if statement was cut off)

[image]

Here's what AccountContext looks like
[image]

If I didn't provide enough information then please let me know

How do I map the "User" Entity?

Comment: Add mapping of user entity to question.

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` on that Exception?

Comment: It occurs directly on declaring the new AccountContext. It doesn't look like there's any InnerException

Comment: This is happened to me too - exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class hierarchy there and there are three different strategies for inheritance mapping: [TPH, TPT and TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

As far as I understand in all three strategies you need to include the **Base class** into you DbContext:

```
public class AccountContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseModel> BaseModels { get; set; }
}
```

This leads automatically to TPH mapping. For the other two strategies you need additional mappings either by data annotations or in Fluent API.

**Edit**

To query for your derived classes (like `User`) you can work with the `OfType` method, for instance:

```
UserDb.BaseModels.OfType<User>().ToList()
```

This would return all entities of type `User` into a list.

Comment: I tried this exactly - and it still complained about not being mapped.

Comment: @Indebi: Can you show the code for the `BaseModel` and `User` class. Do you have any mapping in Fluent API code?