# Entity Framework - Inheritance - Status Pattern - Error: "The type was not mapped"

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to implement the status pattern with Entity Framework 5 Code First.

My scenario have an abstract partial base class named LotStatus and 5 class that inherits from this one: OpenStatus, AwardedStatus, CancelledStatus, ContractSignedStatus and EvaluationStatus:

```
    public abstract partial class LotStatus { ... }

    public class OpenStatus : LotStatus { ... }
    public class AwardedStatus : LotStatus { ... }
```

In the OnModelCreating from the DBContext I'm adding a configuration to the model builder to Map these entities:

```
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LotStatusConfiguration());
```

The code of LotStatusConfiguration is as follow:

```
    public class LotStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LotStatus>
    {
        public LotStatusConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("LotStatus");
            HasKey(ls => ls.LotStatusID);

            this.Map<OpenStatus>(pk => pk.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(typeof(OpenStatus).AssemblyQualifiedName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
            this.Map<EvaluationStatus>(pk => pk.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(typeof(EvaluationStatus).AssemblyQualifiedName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
            this.Map<AwardedStatus>(pk => pk.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(typeof(AwardedStatus).AssemblyQualifiedName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
            this.Map<ContractSignedStatus>(pk => pk.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(typeof(ContractSignedStatus).AssemblyQualifiedName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
            this.Map<CancelledStatus>(pk => pk.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(typeof(CancelledStatus).AssemblyQualifiedName).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)"));
        }
    }
```

When the EF is trying to create the database it raises an error:

```
    The type 'OpenStatus' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.
```

I don't have any [NotMapped] tag so, What am I doing worng? Some idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I have another status pattern defined in this project. The problem was because in the other status pattern implemented exists another OpenStatus class that inherits from another abstract class (ProcedureStatus).

```
Core.ProcedureAggregate.OpenStatus : ProcedureStatus
Core.LotAggregate.OpenStatus : LotStatus
```

I changed the name of the status to OpenLotStatus and it worked...

```
Core.ProcedureAggregate.OpenStatus : ProcedureStatus
Core.LotAggregate.OpenLotStatus : LotStatus
```

Looks like it's not possible have two classes with the same name although they been defined in different namespaces...

Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to include your entities in the `DbContext` - e.g.

```
public DbSet<LotStatus> LotStatuses { get; set; }
```

See this one for some more details [Entity Not Mapped - Entity Model Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052533/entity-not-mapped-entity-model-framework/6057336#6057336)

Comment: It was included: public DbSet<LotStatus> LotStatus { get; set; }

Comment: then put a full reproducible code for entities and your context and I'll try take a look it later